# How can I safely handle POST parameters in an HTTP Handler using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, handler, httphandler

I'm working on an ASP.Net C# application (my first!) that contains an HTTP Handler within it.  My application works with several parameters that are passed in via the URL.  My question(s) is as follows:

My applications entry point is via the HTTP Handler.  When I enter my ProcessRequest method, I am assigning the values of the URL parameters to variables so that I may do something with the data.
**Question:**  Is this safe, even if I am not setting the value to anything when I call the URL?

In my example: I call `host/handler1.ashx` instead of `host/handler1.ashx?something=foo`

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        string something = context.Request["something"];

        context.Response.Write("Hello World: " + something);
    }
```

When calling the above method using the plain URL with no parameters, it executes just fine, but the string `something` is just blank/null.

Additional questions:
What happens to the variable `something` in the case that I do not explicitly initialize it via the URL?  I understand that it is null, but can this lead to problems?

Is it dangerous or not safe to call the plain URL (i.e. should I **always** call it with parameter values specified)?

What is the best way to call a "clean" ashx URL to start the application but not risk problems?

The application will do a series of subsequent GET redirects as it accumulates values and passes them back to the app via the query string.
Should I do a POST or GET upon initial call of the application?

Sorry for asking the same question multiple ways, but I'm a bit confused on the topic and this is my first time writing an app like this.  Any patience and advice you could provide on how to safely handle and initialize parameters is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `context.Request["something"]` is safe, how you use it is up to you: if `something` isn't specified, you'll get a `null` value. But if you then try to e.g. do `something.Substring(...)` without checking if it's null, you'll throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you, Tim.  That's good to know, I will be sure to implement checks before any operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with omitting parameters to an endpoint.  As the developer you are in charge of enforcing what the client is allowed send to you.  If you expect a parameter and it's missing, throw an error (e.g. `HttpException`).

If you are *creating* or *updating* data (i.e. inserting or updating records in a database) the best method would be a `POST` or `PUT`.

**Edit** - Here is an example of how you can handle the input:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    //Maybe you require a value?
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["something"])) {
        throw new HttpException(400, "You need to send a value!");
    }

    //Maybe you require a certain value?
    if (context.Request["something"] != "beerIsGood") {
        throw new HttpException(400, "You need to send the right value!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know.  So using my original code example, where do I catch and throw the HttpException?  Also, how do I do a `POST` or `PUT` in ASP.NET?  It seems that `GET` is very straight forward, but I'm not really sure how to do a `POST`?

Comment: You can handle the error wherever you would like.  I've updated my answer to give you an example.  As for the `POST` or `PUT`, how is the request being made?  By a form in the browser?  Javascript?  Another web-server?

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!  Another web-server will be calling my application ... specifically it will be the Twilio service making a call to my app.

Comment: Well that other web-service might dictate if you need to listen for a `GET`, `POST` so I would look into that first.  Also for what it's worth you would be much better off using WebAPI instead of an ashx HttpHandler.

Comment: They give the option of either `GET` or `POST` ... I will def look into WebAPI.

Comment: @K997 If this answer helped you with your problem then you should consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it.

Comment: Apologies, I got caught up with the project .. thanks for all the feedback, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The Internet is dangerous.

Comment: Ha, it is isn't it? ;)